# li bullet point needs background color

Tags: html, css

I want my `<li>` list items bullet point to be included with the background color of the list. It currently looks like the second example where the bullet point has no background color, but I want it to look like the first:

[image]

How would I add the background color to the bullet point?

Comment: I want to have a background from dot to the end of text

Comment: You need to clearly state what your goal is, what you did and what you've tried to do to fix the problem.  You should start or end with a very specific question.

Comment: add some example of what you have already done

Comment: The question is vague, but I understand it. Downvoters show your face.

Answer (score 6):

You want this.

```
li {
  list-style-position: inside;

}
```

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not easy to understand. Could you post an example of your code for us to help you better please?

From what I can make out, you have a `li` that you want to add a background colour to, but you don't want it to start after the dot (`•`), but include the dot as well?

The property you are after is: `list-style-position: inside;`

```css
li {
  background-color:red;
  list-style-position: inside;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>asdf</li>
  <li>qwer</li>
  <li>zxcv</li>
</ul>
```